# Current state of Serre's Motives conjectures in Seattle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, algebraic-cycles

It would be worth if we have a current state of the conjectures of

> Propriétés conjecturales des groupes de Galois motiviques et des représentations l-adiques. J P Serre. *In Motives, Seattle*

And most important, which ones have been proved..?

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2434.pdf) is an example of work dedicated to the solution of one of these conjectures.

Has there been any proof of some of them since then?

Comment: Can you post the conjectures?

Comment: @Keller, they are a lot. Of out of 13 sections, each section has approximately 10 conjectures. I think the question ask for a summary of a well informed person (?). http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/055.1/